# MYSQL: How to make it virtual column in select Query?

Tags: mysql

Below is the my question any one have idea how to resolve this issue:

Example Query:

```
SELECT id, table2.id as global_id, table3.id as global_id 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
  ON ( table1.id = table2.tab1_id ) 
LEFT JOIN table3 
  ON ( table1.id = table3.tab1_id ) 
WHERE etc etc
```

Basically i don't want to write two times "global_id" column in the select statement and also in the some rows have id = NULL

Can you please write working query here. How can i get id value of all rows in the global_id column ?

Thanks

Comment: Use `SELECT ... UNION ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT table1.id, COALESCE(table2.id, table3.id) as global_id 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
  ON ( table1.id = table2.tab1_id ) 
LEFT JOIN table3 
  ON ( table1.id = table3.tab1_id ) 
WHERE etc etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need this:

```
SELECT id, table2.id as global_id
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
  ON ( table1.id = table2.tab1_id ) 
WHERE etc etc
UNION ALL
SELECT id, table3.id as global_id 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table3 
  ON ( table1.id = table3.tab1_id ) 
WHERE etc etc
```

Comment: You mean i've to write each query with UNION ALL ? no but it is not solution sorry

Comment: it's not clear what you wanted then, please clarify the question